# How can I remotely wipe the contents of a Linux Laptop if its been stolen?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, tools, destruction

I am currently investigating using Linux Laptops for my development team. We currently run Windows. The one advantage that keeps coming up for Windows over Linux from a system administration / security perspective is the fact that if a laptop is stolen, it can be remotely wiped upon boot.

I have been trying to find information on this capability for Linux based workstations, but I have come up empty handed. Do any of you use Linux in an Enterprise environment on Workstations and if so, has this been a requirement that you have solved? I'm not sure where else to look.

Thank you

Comment: you should look for some kind of whole disk encryption solutions supported on Linux...

Comment: I think we have that - but the remote wipe capability is still a barrier.

Comment: Why would you need remote wipe on boot if you have whole disk encryption? If the laptop is stolen while the data is unlocked you're SOL, and if you don't trust the encryption then what's to stop someone transferring the data to another computer before cracking it, without ever rebooting or connecting to the Internet?

Comment: Are you sure this can be done on boot ? because you need at least a remote connexion to the laptop to be able tell that you want a remote wipe. So I guess this would be done after boot while the laptop is on "login" state ... but as file carving tools are now very efficient, wouldn't it be better to consider encryption of the hard drives ?

Comment: Continuing what @noktec mentioned, even for Windows, the remote wipe capabilities are, well... limited. Given an ideal set of circumstances, sure the laptop will be wiped - but it is easy for a smart attacker to prevent that, and thus prevent the wipe. That would only work either for a clueless attacker, or one that is willing to play by your rules :)

Comment: Oh, and btw - welcome to [security.se]! I hope you stick around, these are interesting requirements.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at [Protecting a Laptop from Simple and Sophisticated Attacks](https://grepular.com/Protecting_a_Laptop_from_Simple_and_Sophisticated_Attacks). It's probably the best introduction to laptop security I've seen.

Comment: @notec I might have misstated the question, but yes, my assumption is that it would have to happen after startup - not at boot - as the communication of the wipe command would have to be sent over the internet.

Comment: @notec I think we have an idea on the disk encryption - this is also a requirement.  However, the argument is that our Windows machines are able to be remotely wiped and we do not have that capability on Linux right now.  While there is an argument that someone worth their weight wouldn't boot the machine to access the data, but mount the disk as a secondary drive, the remote wipe capability is still a requirement by our security department - hence the question.   There is little information about Linux on Laptops taking into account enterprise security requirements that I've found.

Answer (score 16):

I've had a look and I think [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/159401) provides some interesting options. I'll summarise them here:

- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdaX` copies zeros over your whole disk. `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` recursively deletes all files on a disk, overriding the `rm -rf /` warning on systems where that is enabled. If you can get to a box via ssh, running the `dd` variant should pretty effectively destroy your disk.
- The grub option is interesting in that it gives you VNC access - however it would likely be obvious to the attacker that you're launching VNC - they'd need to hit the right grub option for starters! A hidden grub menu with the real launch entry *might* suffice... but we're talking about trickery.
- [This AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24133/is-it-possible-to-do-a-remote-wipe-of-a-system) question deals with this issue too, recommending a solution.

---

If you're prepared to do some work yourself, you could configure a very-early-stage `init` entry with sysvinit or whatever your system uses - check a url you control e.g. `https://remotecheck.yourcompany.com` and if the device is stolen, begin a wipe.

The ultimate problem with any remote wipe solution is invoking it - you need to be able to access the device. The reason I mention using a custom init-invoked job is that it is more likely you'll have access out than direct or known access in - i.e. if the attacker is behind a router at their base of operations, chances are good that outbound connections are allowed and much lower that they have an IP you can bind to and allow incoming connections on.

Of course, none of these solutions actually guarantee anything - if the attacker knows how they work they can just turn them off. A solution mentioned in comments is to use disk encryption, which will make the disk unreadable under these caveats:

- the **whole** disk is encrypted - otherwise your software might write to unencrypted areas.
- the system is powered off or for example `luksSuspend -wipe` has been run to remove the keys from memory.
- the attacker has had no way to observe the key entry prior to stealing the device.

Honestly - I'd go with disk encryption.

Answer (score 7):

The data may be protected by encrypting the hard disk with Truecrypt for example but this is not enough...

**EDIT:** check the important comment of Oliver Salzburg about the difference between HD vs Data encryption.

I think the best way to protect and, sometimes, to recover, a stolen laptop is to use an application dedicated for this purpose such as *Prey* or *LoJack*. LoJack for example use some low level features in some laptop model to protect it even the hard disk is removed... This is called a *"persistence module"* installed in some computers models.

Check at *Absolute Software* web site for a list of computers/models with this technology.

Also look at (*for example*):

LoJack:  http://www.absolute.com/en/lojackforlaptops/home.aspx

Prey:  http://preyproject.com/

Hope this help. Let us know.

Comment: In fact, it may be more desirable to not encrypt the OS hard drive, so that the operating system (and Prey) can run if the laptop is stolen. This might allow you to track down the device. You should still make sure your *data* is encrypted though.

Comment: Thank you for this information about Prey and crypted HD vs encrypted data.

Comment: A friend also recommended looking at [Intel Active Management Technology](http://www.intel.com/technology/platform-technology/intel-amt/)

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick option I'll throw out there: have it create an SSH tunnel on boot.

You'll have full control over all it's resources as long as it has an internet connection from work. Need to wipe it? Wipe it. Need to grab a file from someone out of the office? Install software? Mount a server resource for them? Install VNC and punch another tunnel and remote assist them.

I believe you can edit a sshd config file so that on tunnel creation with a specific PC you can automate a wipe and log that it's been done.

If anyone else thinks a good idea, I guess we can start poking around as to the viability of it.

---

Of course if you have full disk encryption, they'll have to boot into the OS to get to this point (as it is now, with Windows, you cannot wipe them until they've cracked your disk encryption, which likely means they've already cloned everything... if you're doing full disk encryption anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I use LUKS to encrypt entire hard disk.

If you install Scientific Linux 6 or recent Fedora, you can find a check box to encrypt it.
It will require a passphrase at startup.